# Trigger complete keybind mapping using <C-O> when in Insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I know that when I am in insert mode I can enter Normal mode for one command only and automatically switch back to insert mode using `<C-O>`. For example to go to the end of the line when in Insert mode I could type `<C-O>$`

I have the following key mapping to format the current paragraph:

```
nnoremap <leader>fp mtvipgw`t
```

I would like to trigger this whilst in insert mode by typing `<C-O><leader>fp`. Unfortunately this doesn't work and I'm sent back into insert mode after the first command only (`mt`) and then the rest of the mapping is typed as normal characters.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Doesn't `gw` already put the cursor back in the right spot? Why the marks? I think you could just do `<C-o>gwip`

Comment: Because I didn't know about `gw` behavior in insert mode. Your point is useful and correct, thanks. 
The question is about triggering multiple commands sequentially after using <C-O>, and the accepted answer is about that problem, not `gw` specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue is that you are actually trying to execute several commands while `<C-o>` only allows to run one. What you could do is create a user defined command which will be executed as only one command but will run everything you need:

```
command! FormatParagraph normal! mtvipgw`t
nnoremap <leader>fp :FormatParagraph<CR>
```

See [`:h user-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#user-commands) also, maybe you'd be interested in [`:h i_CTRL-\_CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-%5c_CTRL-O) to avoid playing with marks.

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't aware of user defined commands (only functions). <C-\> looks good too. Thanks statox!